# splitting the array and send the values to hashset in awk

Tags: awk, split

I am getting var as argument from shell script to awk

```
awk -v var = "blah1|blah2|blah3" -f awk_script.awk
```

I need to put each blah's into a hashset, currently, I am doing it like this. I am getting it into an array and looping through the array and putting it into a hashset. **Can I do better like getting the var and putting the variables directly into a hashset instead of parsing the var into an array first?**

```
    split(var,arr,"|");
    for ( i = 1; i <= length(arr); i++ )
    {
            dest = arr[i];
            exclusion_destinations[dest];
    }
```

down the line, I check

```
if ( dest in exclusion_destinations )
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: By the way: the first array index from `split` is `1` (not `0`)...

Comment: EDITED question. I came to know that when I was testing that it starts from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only construct that sets many array elements at once is the `split` function (at least in standard awk, GNU awk may have other possibilities). This assigns to numerical indices. So you can't escape a loop if you want to make an associative array.

You can, however, change your exclusion test not to use an array. If the strings to exclude don't contain any regexp special character (`().?*+[]\^$`), you can treat the value of `var` as a regexp to match against, with a little tweaking. This may be slightly slower than using an array, but probably not measurably so unless you have a lot of strings to exclude.

```
BEGIN { exclude = "^(" var ")$" }
match(dest, exclude) { … }
```

Another approach is to treat `var` as a concatenation of strings to exclude; `dest` is to be excluded if is appears in `var` between `|`. This will be again slower than a regexp match, but only measurably so for sufficiently large exclusion lists.

```
BEGIN { exclude = "|" var "|" }
index(dest, exclude) { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your second *"down the line"* dest is from an input file which contains values you check against the excluded values (eg. call this input file "data").
You can read in your list  of excluded values  via another file (eg. called "exclude"). If *exclude* is already delimited by `|`, just use sed to change them to `\n`.

Create test files

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<"blah1 blah2 abcde" >data
sed 's/|/\n/g' <<<"blah1|blah2|blah3" >exclude
```

The script

```
awk '{
  if( NR==FNR ) { exclude[$0]++ 
  }else{ 

    # somewhere later on
    # "dest" to be tested is $1 of "data"
    if( exclude[$1] ) print "do something", $1 
  }
}' exclude data
```

or something like this for passing the 2 "files" may suit.:

```
}' <(sed 's/|/\n/g' <<<"blah1|blah2|blah3") \
   data
```

Output

```
do something blah1
do something blah2
```